# How to Get BabylonJS working in a Microsoft Teams App

Tags: microsoft-teams, babylonjs

In a Microsoft Teams app, I am using

```
await app.shareAppContentToStageAsync()
```

with a page that hosts Babylon JS - this exact page that should show a ball on a plane with a blue background.
https://doc.babylonjs.com/setup/starterHTML
This works fine on Teams on the web running on Microsoft Edge.

In the Teams Desktop client on Windows 11 Version 1.6.00.2573 (64-bit), all I see is the blue background.

Is there anything I need to do to in order to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the playground frame, you may need to enable the playground origin in the tab manifest (see [validDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains) parameter) because the ball and the blue background thing is rendered from an origin that is different from the main page origin (https://**playground**.babylonjs.com/full.html#WJXQP0)

If you try to add the playground page directly as a tab (using the link above and the built-in "WebSite" app for example) it seems to work fine in the Desktop Client as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Windows Microsoft Teams desktop client has a bug in the WebGL2 component and I have to initialize the engine with a parameter disabling the WebGL2 Support:

```
const engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true, {
        disableWebGL2Support: true});
```